# How to change my iMessage Apple ID to a phone number?

Tags: messages

I need to know how I can use my cell phone number to send and receive messages instead of my email address.

When I go to my settings to change my number, it is in grey and my email address is in black and I need to know how I can fix that.

Comment: Do you use iMessage on iOS or OS X? the steps to change from an email to a phone number as "caller ID" are similar but different enough that potential answerers have to guess what your setup involves. Please edit more information into the question.

Comment: This is old question, so i add this as a comment (not an answer)... but I just had this where my phone number showed up gray AND could not receive iMessages (no checkmark).  I turned off iMessage and turned it back on again a few times, and eventually it registered my phone with iMessage properly.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the line is greyed out, the checkbox next to your phone number in Settings > Messages indicates it is being used for sending and receiving messages. The email address(es) listed indicate that iMessage also looks for iMessages sent to those address(es), and will deliver them as if they were sent to your phone number (so long as each one has a checkmark next to it as well).

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone uses the Messages app to send messages to other devices. However, it works a bit differently depending on what device the person you are messaging is using.

When you send a Message, the iPhone looks on Apple servers to see if the recipient owns an Apple Device. Remember when you had to register your device with an Apple ID? This was putting your 'email' in the Apple server. It also put your telephone number in the Apple server.

If the server finds your recipient in the Apple servers, it automatcially sends a message via the Apple network, therefore not using the SMS network, which might incur charges (depending on your SMS or text message limits).

If the Apple server does not find your recipient, then it sends the message via SMS or text messaging, over the carriers system. So, if you send a message to a friend who has an Android phone, the Apple server won't find that device in its database, and will then send the message via regular text messaging service, so the Android phone can receive it.

This systems allows you to message anyone, and Apple simply figures out the best way to send the message, whether its via Apple's system, which does not incur SMS fees, or via the carrier's system, which might incur fees. (most users in the USA have unlimited text messaging plans these days, so this is less than a concern. If you have a limit of 100 messages, you can appreciate how this is a good thing.)

**OK, now to your question**: ***your email***: Messages is NOT sending a message via email. It is simply using the email (which is likely your Apple ID), as an **identifier** of your device. This lets other Apple users send you a message to either your phone number or email address. This is useful on iPads, iPod Touch, and Macs, who can not send to phone numbers, because they do not have phone service. So, with Messages on your iPhone, someone on their Mac can send you a message, and you can message back!

Answer (score -2):

Go to `Settings > Messages > Send & Receive`. Select the info icon by your email and choose `Remove This Email`. Then turn on sms, turn off iMessage and after a minute turn imessage on again and the email should be gone.

Comment: this email is likely the Apple ID