# Getting a Text from someone that does not have my mobile number but has my email

Tags: text, mobile-mail

I am getting text on my iPhone from clients that do not have my mobile number.  Is it possible that they are sending text using my email address that is linked to my iCloud account?

Comment: Yes, if you have it configured to receive text messages that.

Comment: What colour are the messages?

Comment: Messages are gray, like normal incoming text

Comment: Thank you found the setting and have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Mario and welcome to Ask Different community. Yes, this is possible and you may have it configured from Settings to receive SMS through your email. As pointed in this related question [cant get my number to change from email to my phone number](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153883/cant-get-my-number-to-change-from-email-to-my-phone-number)

> Messages is NOT sending a message via email. It is simply using the email (which is likely your Apple ID), as an identifier of your device. This lets other Apple users send you a message to either your phone number or email address. This is useful on iPads, iPod Touch, and Macs, who can not send to phone numbers, because they do not have phone service. So, with Messages on your iPhone, someone on their Mac can send you a message, and you can message back!